# Looping associated cookies and storing them in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I have a small script that sets multiple cookies, they all have this format `item_1928` `item_3847` `item_5782` etc.

I need to get all the values for the cookies that start with `item` and store them in an array.

Here's is some code I found on SO but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. It just stores the key, but not the values:

```
$matches = array();
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
  if(substr($key, 0, 20) == 'wordpress_logged_in_') {
    $matches[] = $key;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
  if(strstr($key ,"item_")) {
    $matches[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify that code like this:

```
$matches = array();
$values = array();
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
  if(substr($key, 0, 20) == 'wordpress_logged_in_') {
    $matches[] = $key;
    $values[] = $_COOKIE[$key];
  }
}
```

Then you'll have all the values (and NOT the keys) in the `$values` array.